# Setting a website's application pool in IIS using Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, application-pool

I need a Powershell command that does the equivalent of adding a website in IIS, but need the bindings for the "Application pool":

[image]

So far I can add a website doing this:

```
New-Item iis:\Sites\swmarket -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation="80:swmarket"} -physicalPath c:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

But I don't know how to set the "Application pool" in the new website. Any way to see all the bindings?

Comment: If you have Powershell 3, try this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807831.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Set-ItemProperty iis:\Sites\swmarket -Name applicationpool -Value swmarket
```

Alternatively, with Powershell 3, you could do this:

```
New-WebAppPool -Name $WebSiteName
New-Website -Name $WebSiteName -ApplicationPool $WebSiteName -HostHeader $WebSiteName -PhysicalPath $PathInfo -Port 80
Set-Content $PathInfo\default.htm “PSCreated Default Page”
```

Check out the MS Technet description [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807831.aspx)

Comment: Looks like it is case-sensitive.  Should be applicationPool, not applicationpool.